# Spring 6 HTTP Interface caching

Tags: java, spring, http

When using the new Spring HTTP Interface, how do you make it's methods "cacheable", using the `@Cacheable` annotation?

I have the following interface:

```
@HttpExchange(url = "/v1/example", accept = "application/json", contentType = "application/json")
public interface ExampleClient {

    @GetExchange(url = "/test")
    @Cacheable("example")
    ResponseEntity<ExampleClientResponse> test();
}
```

The proxy is generated in this way:

```
HttpServiceProxyFactory
                .builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient))
                .blockTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                .build()
                .createClient(ExampleClient.class);
```

My main class is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and `@EnableCaching`.

By just adding the `@Cacheable` annotation to the `test()` method the cache does not work.

Comment: Hi @Toniotti. Did you find a solution ? I'm facing the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Caching works fine for me with the HTTP interface. Sample app on [github](https://github.com/devatherock/spring-boot-demo/compare/http-exchange?expand=1)